# Question about python3 list deletion。Why can't I delete an even number with an odd number?

Tags: python, list

**I entered a line of code**

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for i in li :

    if i%2 == 0:
        li.remove(i)
print(li)
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

**it‘s ok**

**two**

```
li = [2,4,5,6,7]

for i in li :

    if i%2 == 0:
        li.remove(i)

print(li)
[4, 5, 7]
```

**it's ok ，But I don’t know why**

**three**

```
li = [2,6,4,5,4,7]

for i in li :

    if i%2 == 0:
        li.remove(i)
print(li)
[6, 5, 7]
```

**it's ok ，Same as the second one， but I do not know why**

**four**

```
li = [2,6,4,5,6,7]

for i in li :

    if i%2 == 0:
        li.remove(i)
print(li)
[5, 6, 7]
```

**I broke down**

**five**

```
li = [2,6,5,6,6,7]

for i in li :

    if i%2 == 0:
        li.remove(i)
print(li)[5, 6, 6, 7]
```

**Sorry, I don't know English very much, with the help of Google Translate**

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Look on stackoverflow for questions with "how to delete or remove list elements in a loop" in Python. This has often been asked. Short answer: You can't, because it breaks your loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the list while looping over it which means after every number you remove the loop will avoid the first value after the removed value and take the second next value till the loop end.

You can make a copy of the list to iterate over and remove from the original one as follows:

```
li = [2,6,5,6,6,7]
li_copy = li.copy()
for i in li_copy :

    if i%2 == 1:
        li.remove(i)

print(li)
```

Comment: More common in Python is to use slice notation: `for i in li[:]:`

Answer (score 2):

As @Lennart Regebro mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), since your modifying the list each time you 're iterating over it, it's safer to get a copy of that list and iterate over that copy, because you will get unexpected results otherwise:

```
li = [2,6,5,6,6,7]

for i in li[:]: #Notice the [:] notation, it is used to create a copy of a list.
    if i%2 == 0:
        li.remove(i)

print(li)
```

Result:

```
[5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed Hawary has pointed out your mistake. You can also try this, list comprehension makes it very easy to modify existing list based on any condition.

[i for i in li if i%2!=0]

Comment: If you surround your code with grave marks (looks like an apostrophe, but slightly different), it sets the code off like this `[i for i in li if i%2!=0]`